# The loop of x-th root that always end up the same

Tags: real-analysis

I was playing with my calculator for about 20 minutes I found out that following 
function:
$$(x+1)^{1/x}$$
when it is looped enough time with any initial input x$\geq$0
I have run this loop on the first 100 integers and my results in all of those inputs were all 1.7767750400970548.

I then ran the loop on decimal numbers and I still got the same result, except for some cases such as 1.7, 1.8, 2.4, etc where the 16-th decimal place was 6 instead of 8.

I don't know what really is happening or why is the function behaving like this.
Can somebody please explain to me what is going on.

Thank you

Comment: You have found the solution to $x=(x+1)^{1/x}$ or the non-zero solution to $x^x-x-1=0$.  More digits (and slightly greater precision) on your calculator would show $x \approx 1.776775040097054697479730744\ldots$

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You rediscovered the fixed-point method to solve equations.

You are computing the sequence

$$x_{n+1}=(x_n+1)^{1/x_n}.$$

Then if the iterates converge to some value, let $x_\infty$, this value must be such that

$$x_\infty=(x_\infty+1)^{1/x_\infty}.$$ Hence you solve an equation of the form $x=f(x)$. Theory allows to establish under what condition such a sequence converges.

---

Now you probably also observed a numerical phenomenon: as floating-point arithmetic is not exact, you are computing a numerical version of this sequence, which might end in several distinct values, or even distinct cycles, that you reach from distinct starting values. This is much harder to study and will depend on the particular implementation of the floating-point unit.

---

**Final note:**

You can replace the fixed-point iterations

$$x=f(x)$$ by

$$x=\frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{f'(x)-1}$$ ($f'$ is the first derivative of $f$). This also converges to a solution of $x=f(x)$, and can converge much faster.